# Python Pandas: dataFrame.info() throws KeyError: 0

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

My script splits a column into two parts. Thereafter I rename the column 0.

```
df3=df_global['title'].str.rsplit('-', n=3, expand=True)
df3.rename(columns={0: 'Catalogue ID'}, inplace=True)
```

When I now type

```
df3.info()
```

it throws `KeyError: 0`

I renamed the columns in other dfs (df1, df2) as well and never get an error.

Comment: What is the output of `df3.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: I don't use "....tolist()

Comment: Your error basically means, that there's no column by the name `0` in your `df3`. Hence, I asked you to check the output of `df3.columns.tolist()`.

Comment: `str.split` return `0` columns by default, if not, it means some problem in `df_global['title']`, maybe `df_global` is empty

Comment: So is possible test `print (df_global['title'])` for data which failed?

Comment: the df3.columns.tolist() returns ['Catalogue ID', 1, 2, 3]

Comment: Df2 extracts data from the same table and does not throw the error.

Comment: `df2=df_global['title'].str.rsplit('-', n=1, expand=True)
df2.rename(columns={0: 'title', 1: 'Variable'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: Can you try to add at least one more column when you are renaming the df3 such as `df3.rename(columns={0: 'Catalogue ID', 1: 'Test' }, inplace=True)`?